# Is there any reason that the STL does not provide functions to return an iterator via index?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Is there a reason that the STL does not provide functions to return an iterator into a container via an index?

For example, let's say I wanted to insert an element into a `std::list` but at the nth position. It appears that I have to retrieve an iterator via something like `begin()` and add `n` to that iterator. I'm thinking it would be easier if I could just get an iterator at the nth position with something like, `std::list::get_nth_iterator(n)`.

I suspect I have misunderstood the principles of the STL. Can anyone help explain?

Thanks
BeeBand

Comment: Thanks Everyone. Its clear I should be using a `std::vector`.

Comment: Using a `vector<>` if you have the option and random access is important is definitely the thing to do.  But if random access isn't more important than constant-time insertion (for example) or  if you're writing generic code (a template) and you don't want to force users of it to use a container with random access iterators, `std::advance()` will help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `advance()` from the `<iterator>` header:

<strike>`list<foo>::iterator iter = advance(someFooList.begin(), n);`</strike>

```
list<foo>::iterator iter = someFooList.begin();

std::advance( iter, n);
```

If the iterator supports random access (like `vector`) it'll work quite efficiently, if it only supports increasing (or decreasing) the iterator, like `list`, it'll work but only as well as can be.

Comment: The code above generates a syntax error because std::advance() returns void. The code should read `iter = someFooList.begin(); advance(iter, n);`

Comment: I'm sorry - I posted in haste just before a meeting, and like nearly all code that I don't actually compile, this was wrong. I've corrected it. std::advance() takes a reference to an iterator that gets updated rather than returning a new iterator. It's probably specified like that to reasonably support things like input-only iterators (since in that case, if `advance()` took a value parameter rather than a reference, the iterator passed to `advance()` would return a different item when dereferenced after `advance()` returns. The interface `advance()` uses makes that a bit more evident).

Answer (score 5):

`std::list` is a linked list. So it does not support random access. To get to the nth position in the list, you have to start at the beginning and move through all the nodes until you arrive at n. This is pretty expensive (O(n)), and thus it's bad to have a method that does not suggest this expense. `get_nth_iterator(n)` implies getting the iterator that points to the nth node is cheap.

`std::vector` of course supports this directly with the `[]` operator, because the datastructure supports random access and so this is very inexpensive for it.

Comment: Actually if `get_nth_iterator()` were a free function, then the implication is that it might not be efficient. Consider `std::vector<int> n; ... n.erase(std::remove(n.begin(), n.end(), 12), n.end());`

Comment: Oops... sorry... didn't realize that `get_nth_iterator()` was a proposed method of `std::list`.

Answer (score 2):

std::list isn't random-access container, so there is no reason for accessing n-th element. if you need this, consider using std::vector instead..

Comment: There are, unfortunately, sometimes good reasons to access the nth element of a list.  Vectors and lists are efficient at different things, and sometimes you have to do different things with the same data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, anything that might be costly is made a bit clumsy, so you won't do it by accident. Using your example, with a container that provides random access iterators it would be simply `container.begin()+n`, but for an `std::list` (which provides a forward iterator) you'd need to use `list.begin()` followed by `advance()`.

If you want to get the N<sup>th</sup> iterator, chances are that you just shouldn't be using `std::list` in the first place. Then again, if you started that sentence at "chances", it would remain *nearly* as true...